# How to display custom site field with stored value in site edit form using Aikau framework in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, aikau

I'm able to create custom site field in alfresco using Aikau framework and also successfully able to store the value, i got to know that i should modify modules/edit-site.js file. But i don't know the procedure to display it in edit site form.

I tried using widgetsForEditSiteDialog in site-header, It is displaying the field but not the value.

Kindly help

Comment: what is your alfresco version? 5.0.x or 5.1 ?

Comment: Hi, I’m using Alfresco 5.2

Comment: Check this answer : https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2016/11/23/create-and-edit-site-customization